# Inverse Laplace Transform of ${1/s^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}x^a$ by contour integration

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration

In question 1) we get Laplace transform of $$ g(t) = t^a $$ is:

$$\hat g(t)= {1/s^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}x^a$$

then I was stuck at question 2) which asks me to evaluate the inverse laplace transform of $ \hat g(p) $ which is

$$
{1/2\pi i}\int_0^\infty e^{pt}\hat g(p)dp
$$

I know the answer should be $ t^a $ as the inverse transform comes back to itself, but I cannot figure out how to make the contour integration. I tried to apply Cauchy's residue theorem to eliminate the $ 1/2 \pi i $ but was stuck then. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I don't understand the form of $\hat{g}(t)$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm g}\pars{t}\equiv t^{a}\quad\imp\quad
     \hat{\rm g}\pars{s} = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a}\expo{-st}\,\dd t
     ={\Gamma\pars{a + 1} \over s^{a + 1}}}$
where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
[Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$. Also,
$\ds{{\rm g}\pars{t}
     =\int_{\gamma - \infty\ic}^{\gamma + \infty\ic}
      {\Gamma\pars{a + 1} \over s^{a + 1}}\,\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,,
      \qquad\gamma > 0}$.

> \begin{align}
> {\rm g}\pars{t}&
> =\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\int_{\gamma - \infty\ic}^{\gamma + \infty\ic}
> {\expo{st} \over s^{a + 1}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}=\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\times
> \\[3mm]&\bracks{%
> -\int_{-\infty}^{0}\pars{-s}^{-a - 1}\expo{-\pars{a + 1}\pi\ic}\expo{st}
> {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\int_{0}^{-\infty}\pars{-s}^{-a - 1}\expo{\pars{a + 1}\pi\ic}\expo{st}
> {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
> \\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\bracks{%
> \expo{-\pi a\ic}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-a - 1}\expo{-st}
> {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\expo{\pi a\ic}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-a - 1}\expo{-st}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over \pi}\,\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\,
> {\expo{\pi a\ic} - \expo{-\pi a\ic} \over 2\ic}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-a - 1}\expo{-st}\dd s
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{\Gamma\pars{a + 1} \over \pi}\,\sin\pars{\pi a}t^{a}\
> \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-a - 1}\expo{-s}\dd s}_{\ds{=\ \Gamma\pars{-a}}}
> \end{align}

$$
{\rm g}\pars{t}
={\Gamma\pars{1 + a}\Gamma\pars{-a}\sin\pars{-\pi a} \over \pi}\,t^{a}
$$

> With [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm)
>   ${\bf\mbox{6.1.17}}$,
>   $\ds{{\Gamma\pars{1 + a}\Gamma\pars{-a}\sin\pars{-\pi a} \over \pi} = 1}$
>   such that

$$
\color{#44f}{\large{\rm g}\pars{t} = t^{a}}
$$